# CURL not working to grab HTML content

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap, curl

I have a CMS at one URL and at least 68 property sites running off that CMS each at different domains.

I am trying to grab a form from one of the property sites to display in a modal in the CMS (to allow other properties to see the form to decide if they want to include it as well.)

On the bootstrap page, I have this script:

```
(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.btnModal', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var formID = $(this).data('form');

        $.ajax({
            url:  "<?= site_url('staffer/get_form_modal'); ?>",
            type: "POST",
            data: { fid: formID },
            success: function(msg){
                $('#modal-body').html(msg);
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            } // end success
        });
    });
})(); // end self-invoking anonymous function
```

In the controller, this is the CURL code:

```
public function get_form_modal($fid = null){
    if(!$fid){ $fid = $this->input->post('fid'); }
    $form = $this->istaff_m->get_modal_form($fid);
    $html = '';

    $url = $this->boilerplate['propertyInfo'][0]['istaffURL'] . 'staff/' . $form[0]->URL;
    // $url echos http://istaff.edrtest.com/staff/res_lr
    $url = (string) trim(strip_tags($url));
    $url = str_replace('&amp;', '&', $url);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)"); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result= curl_exec ($ch);
    if( $result === false){
        echo "Curl error: " . @curl_error($ch);
    } // end if
    curl_close ($ch);

    echo $result;
} // end get_form_modal function
/*-----------------------------------------------------*/
```

The modal pops up with its header and an empty body. No error message ... just blank.

Firebug shows the form ID being posted and an empty response -- again, no error message.

Any help is appreciated!

UPDATE: Using SSH on the server, I ran 'curl -I 'http://istaff.edrtest.com/staff/res_lr' and got back the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 16 Dec 2013 16:15:56 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: keep-alive
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Refresh: 0;url=http://istaff.edrtest.com/user/log_in
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=kbc674bc07nn4aeh2k5rsur685; path=/
X-Powered-By: PleskLin
```

Comment: Try adding `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);`. See if that helps you debug.

Comment: No change ... still no error message.

Comment: Test if your CURL request works without AJAX by calling the method directly.

Comment: Nope, still white page. This is why I added the optional URL parameter to test directly. (At least I did one thing right)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From response-- Refresh: 0;url=http://istaff.edrtest.com/user/log_in

Don't you think you need to be as a logged in user to perform this curl operation?

Also, are your sure its requires GET operation? It can be a POST operation( I advice you to check this again).

Comment: since I am in control of both URLS, I can control either. But to further debug, shouldn't at least the login page be returned? I am getting NOTHING.

Comment: You will not get anything. Because your browser is instructed to redirect to the login url through the HTTP header Refresh. Now its your duty to do this redirection from your code :-)

Comment: Can I pass credentials through CURL?

Comment: yes, try using these curl opts: CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLOPT_USERPWD